# fill 2D array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hello every one I want to ask how to fill 2D array using pointer. I know how to fill 1D array 
like

```
*(i+array) = 0;
```

but if i have array like this

```
int array[5][10] ;
int * rowptr ;
int * colptr ;
```

how should I initialize my 2D array using pointers

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
*(*(array+i)+j) = value;
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `i[array][j]`, which is similarly far away from the usual form: `array[i][j]`.

Comment: The question specified "using pointers".  (Of course the `[]` operator does use pointers.)